# Erlang: check chars in inserting text if chars exists in list

Tags: erlang, erl

What I'm looking for is, if inserted text contains chars and integer and if these not in List chars return false

Example List:

```
List = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
```

And the function should have 1 value like :

```
check(Text) ->
    List = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"],
```

if the inserting text like is :

```
check("you should have 10 point to do this")
```

should return true cuz every thing in text exists within List

and if the inserting text like is :

```
check("you should + have ....")
```

should return false cuz " + " & " . " not exists within List.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that your first `check` example passes a string containing whitespace, which is not in `List`, so I'm assuming you want to handle that.

Here's one way to solve this:

```
check(Text) ->
    List = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \t\n.",
    lists:all(fun(C) -> lists:member(C, List) end, Text).
```

First, note that here, `List` is not a list of strings, as you originally specified, but a list of characters. I've added the space, tab, newline, and period characters to `List` as well.

The second line of `check/1` walks through the list `Text` character by character. For each character `C` we check that it's a member of `List`. If that test returns true for all characters, then `lists:all/2` returns true, otherwise it returns false.